# Basic question "piecewise linear curve" using vtk (python)

Tags: python, vtk

suppose that I have a piecewise curve in the following format:
curve=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],......[xn,yn,zn]]

how to convert this curve into vtk object and visualize it? I tried a lot of tutorials but they all start from a source object already pre-defined in vtk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering that it is called polyline. a MWE can be found in

https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/PolyLine/